# What is the simplest way to aggregate two numeric arrays in pure Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aggregate

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
```

I want the output to be `[5,7,9]`

What is the simplest syntax that can achieve this in pure Python 3?

Comment: And the uglier version of @BuddyBob's answer : `c = list(map(sum, zip(a, b)))`

Comment: Yes I like your answer @BuddyBob. I will accept it shortly if nothing nicer comes along :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say using `zip()` would be a nice way

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [x+y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

output

```
[5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` to pair the data, then several ways

- `c = [x + y for x, y in zip(a, b)]`
- `c = [sum(pair) for pair in zip(a, b)]`
- `c = list(map(sum, zip(a, b)))`